# Unity hides game objects when the camera rotates around them

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a mix of 3D elements, 2D sprites and 3D TextMeshPro.

Normally they render fine, but when I rotate the camera around them, some elements get hidden or appear to be behind other elements.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

[image: In this rotation, elements on the right are hidden]
[image: In this rotation, elements toward the top-left are hidden]

Comment: what's is hidden?

Comment: In the first image you can see 4 brown animal skin,and in the second image only 3 and they are not the same. Look too the text with the number 5 and the others

Comment: what kind of object are those?

Comment: Try giving them a little offset to the front. And be sure, that the background image is the first item in the hierachy.

Comment: They are 2D sprites and 3D textMeshPro. And Ecco I do that in the images, and you can see that this don't work

Comment: @Ferran hmm maybe try adding a canvas component to each UI element and then click "override sorting" and add 1 or greater value to it.

Comment: yea I'm doing a test using Canvas, I will keep you informed

Comment: @Ferran dont forget to post an answer or confirm to someone who gave you a right move to fix your problem to post here as an answer and approve it! :D good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion

***If you're gonna use a 2D elements in a 3D space use a Canvas***

if only is one 2D element you can use 2D objects in a 3D scene,but if is more than one and you need to put one in front of other use a UI parent and a child UI elements(srites,text)
cause that allow to yuo to not fail in the layers of the objects

Answer (score 0):

For 2D objects, such as sprites or TextMeshPro text elements, rendering is affected by the sort order. You can set the 'sorting layer' for each item and if you need further ability to sort within a layer, you can set the 'order in layer' value (higher number is rendered in front of lower number).

For **Sprite Renderer**, expand 'Additional Settings' in the inspector to see Sorting Layer and Order in Layer.

[image: Additional Settings in inspector for Sprite Renderer]

For **TextMeshPro - Text**, expand 'Extra Settings'.

[image]

This will probably be sufficient. However if you need to add Sorting Layer and Order in Layer to other game objects, you can add the **Sorting Group** component.

Canvas has a particular usage for UI, so I would suggest you use layer sorting rather than moving your items into a canvas.

See also [Unity manual: 2D Sorting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html).